# Finding temporal patterns that predict "life length"

Tags: survival, random-forest, prediction, pattern-recognition, spatio-temporal

I'm doing research on system usage. It is an online system that provide certain information to users, and I want to predict for how long users use the system. I already noticed that if people don't use it for 2 weeks, then it is unlikely that they will use it again. So my "dependent variable" is the length of time between user registration and the point in which they do not do anything for two weeks.

I have a log of every visit to the system and every action the user did. I already did some "aggregate" analysis (e.g. average monthly usage, etc.) and created a random forest on a bunch of such variables. I now look for a more "temporal" approach, that is taking into account when certain types of actions occurred and what are the relations among those times.

I am not an expert on this but I am sure that there is plenty of practical and theoretical work that has been done. So any reference or suggestion (or leading questions) that will direct me will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should look into survival analysis. There are many good books on this topic. What software are you using?

Comment: I am using R. any special package I should look into? any specific topics within survival analysis that I should concentrate on?

Comment: It depends on what you know already. "Time to event" data, especially with censoring, is the classic survival analysis problem.